# Sum of $5$ dice: Number of solutions diophantine equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

Calculate the probability that, when we throw $5$ dice, their sum is $18$. To do this, I figured I need to know how many solutions does this diophantine equation have:
$$\left \{\begin{array}[c]
xx_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=18 \\ 1\leq x_i \leq 6
\end{array} \right \}$$
(Then I calculate the probability knowing that the total amount of possible outcomes is $6^5$).
However I don't know how to calculate the amount of solutions of the equation. Can someone help me?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673834/determine-how-many-integer-solutions-to-the-inequality-x-1x-2-x-5-lt-110/3674138#3674138) is a similar problem.

Comment: And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698795/discrete-mathematics-generating-function/3698943#3698943) is a simpler one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an approach by **generating functions**:

The numbers of solution with the given constraints is
$$[x^{18}](x+\cdots+x^6)^5.$$
Thus,
\begin{align}
[x^{18}](x+\cdots+x^6)^5
&=[x^{18}]x^5(1+x+\cdots+x^5)^5\\
&=[x^{18}]x^5\left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}\right)^5\\
&=[x^{18}]x^5(1-x^6)^5\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+4}{4}x^n\\
&=[x^{13}](1-x^6)^5\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+4}{4}x^n\\
&=[x^{13}](1-5x^6+10x^{12})\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+4}{4}x^n\\
&=\binom{17}{4}-5\binom{11}{4}+10\binom{5}{4}\\
&=780.
\end{align}

Thus, the numbers of solutions is 780.

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting a small typo.  You had typed an exponent of $6$ when you meant $5$.

Comment: How do you go from a polynomial to a sum of combinatorial numbers?

Comment: @fdez I consider only the terms with exponent $x^13$, thus, after doing the products, we conclude that these are the only terms with such exponents. Here in MSE there are many question solved by using generating funciotns, I recommend you visit some of these topics.